# Creating a Lambda Contains expression

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I want to create a class which wraps a list of structures.

I have the following code:

```
public struct MyData
{
    public int ID;
    public string Description;
}

public class MyClass
{
    private List<MyData> data;

    public bool Contains(string desc)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            return data.Contains(item => item.Description.Contains(desc));
        }

        return false;
    }        
}
```

I can't see why I'm unable to use a Lambda expression, the error that I get is:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'MyApp.MyData' because it is not a delegate type
```

Comment: If you are refering to `Enumerable.Contains` it does not accept a lambda as a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) expects you to pass it a `MyData`, if you want to use a lambda for comparison then use [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx)

```
return data.Any(item => item.Description.Contains(desc));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool Contains( string desc )
{
    return data != null && data.Exists( item => item.Description.Contains( desc ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the `List<T>Contains` method expects a `T`, whereas you've given it a lambda expression, created with the `=>`.

What you could do is:

```
data.Any(item => item.Description.Contains(desc));
```